# What is the purpose of this static variable?

Tags: database, laravel

In the Laravel 5.4 documentation there is an [example of a factory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#writing-factories) which includes a static variable `$password`. What is the purpose of this variable?

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Whit static you define that after first creation of password you will use it evetime in loop. So in every iteration bcrypt will not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bcrypt()` is an expensive call, which is part of its advantage as a password hashing algorithm.

Since the fake password being generated is hardcoded to 'secret', there is no need to `bcrypt()` the password every time. By using a `static` variable, we can `bcrypt()` the password once, and then use that same hash value on every subsequent call to the factory (within the same request).

So, for example, imagine you were setting up a test that needed 100 users.

```
$users = factory(User::class, 100)->create();
```

That code will call the factory closure 100 times. Without the static `$password` variable, `bcrypt()` would run 100 times, which could take a couple seconds. With the static variable, `bcrypt()` now only runs once, and the result is used for all 100 users, which greatly increases the speed of your test.